# Как создать связь с service-based Database

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq2sql, база-данных

Всем привет, извиняюсь за простой вопрос т.к чайник. Мне надо создавать динамически таблицы и заполнять их по мере использования программы. Мне посоветовали разобраться с LINQ для этого. За основу взял туториал [туториал](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-LINQ-to-SQL-in-C-Sharp), но уже в самом начале появились проблемы т.к я не понимаю что надо записать в loginString для связи с бд созданной в самом проекте средстави Visual Studio. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться:
Код:

```
[Table(Name = "Employees")]
public class Employee
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public int ID;
    [Column]
    public string Name;
    [Column]
    public string Department;
}

class MyDataBase:DataContext
{
    public Table<Employee> Employees;
    public MyDataBase(string LoginString):base(LoginString)
    { 
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyDataBase db = new MyDataBase(@"что сюда вставлять"); //я что только не пробовал сюда вставлять, все равно не принимает на след строке

        db.ExecuteCommand("CREATE TABLE Employees. (ID int, Name varchar(50), Departament varchar(50))");

        Employee employee1 = new Employee();
        employee1.ID = 101;
        employee1.Name = "John Smith";
        employee1.Department = "Sales";
        db.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(employee1);

        Employee employee2 = new Employee();
        employee2.ID = 102;
        employee2.Name = "Ted Black";
        employee2.Department = "Research";
        db.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(employee2);

        Employee employee3 = new Employee();
        employee3.ID = 103;
        employee3.Name = "Allen Gottlieb";
        employee3.Department = "Sales";
        db.Employees.InsertOnSubmit(employee3);

        db.SubmitChanges();

        var salesDept = from e in db.Employees
                        where e.Department == "Sales"
                        select e;
        foreach (var employee in salesDept)
            Console.WriteLine(employee.Name + " " + employee.ID);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Сюда нужно вставить строку подключения к БД
Её можно написать самому или сгенерить.

Comment: Вот здесь хороший туториал: http://professorweb.ru/my/LINQ/base/level1/info_linq.php

Я не эксперт и за качество материала не ручаюсь, но помог во многом разобраться. Примеры также имеются.

Comment: Попробуй так:

MyDataBase db = new MyDataBase(@"server=имя сервера;database=имя базы;");

или так:

MyDataBase db = new MyDataBase("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename='|DataDirectory|\Test.mdf';Integrated Security=True");